# Вычисление длины вектора

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Переменной R присвоить значение 1, если длина вектора А больше длины вектора В, и значение 0 в противном случае. Вектора A[8], B[8]. Вычисление длины вектора оформить в виде функции.
Помогите, пожалуйста, понять как оформить функцию, ведь когда дан вектор, а не две координаты, совсем не ясно что делать.

Comment: Уточните о каких векторах идет речь.

Comment: @Cerbo, речь идет об одномерных массивах

Comment: @mr. copypast  Массивы целочисленные или действительных чисел?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция для нахождения длины вектора может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <math.h>

//...

double vector_length( const double a[], size_t n )
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) sum += a[i] * a[i];

    return sqrt( sum );
}
```